# Possibly Bug in Websharper Zafir-Libraries (Beta)

Tags: beta, websharper

I'm trying to create a Sitelet with SiteletBuilder in C#:

**return WebSharper.Sitelets.Content.Page(...)**

However, the class **Websharper.Sitelet** contains **Content** both as **Struct** and **Class**.

So, this does not compile.

Versions of Zafir-Libraries are

- Zafir 4.0.152.29-beta5
- Zafir.CSharp 4.0.152.29-beta5
- Zafir.Html 4.0.56.95-beta5
- Zafir.UI.Next 4.0.102.33-beta5

How to reference WebSharper.Sitelets.Content proberly?

Or is this indeed a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report, created ticket: https://github.com/intellifactory/websharper/issues/645

I have been testing with having `using WebSharper.Sitelets;` and then using with shorter form `Content.Page(...)`. C# can resolve this for some reason, although the name conflict indeed exists in `WebSharper.Sitelets.dll`